# Is there a function in ReactJS to wait for a Redux Action to be complete before loading anything in a class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, redux, async-await

Is it possible to wait for a Redux action to be completed before loading anything in the class?

I have a page which uses data from logged-in users and the data is stored in a Redux state. In my React class, I'm calling the data in the Redux state to be used dynamically. If the user isn't logged in, the code will run into an error because the logged-in data is not present. How do I make it such that the code will wait for the Redux action to check if the user is logged-in, then if they are *not* logged in they will be redirected to another page before the data gets rendered and before the error occurs?

Anything like

```
on('REDUX_ACTION_LOGGED_IN', () => {})
```

will be useful.

I also saw an online package about something like `redux-wait-for-action`. Can someone teach me how to implement this here? The documentation isn't very clear.

Answer (score 1):

I think you could look at this a different way.

You could check if the variable/data exists and if not then do something else.

Redux re-renders the component when the state changes. This means you do not have to wait for it to happen.

Something like this in your render probably would do:

```
render(){
    <div>
       {someDataAfter.login ? <div> I am logged in!</div> : <div> I am logged out</div>}
    </div>  
}
```

Just for completeness sake [here is a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) to explain the ? (ternary if) in the render function.

Another solution is to wrap the component with another one. This parent component can check if the user is loggedin. If it is then you can display the logged in component so:

```
render(){
   {loggedIn && <MySecuredComponent/>
}
```

This will not render or load `MySecuredComponent` until `loggedIn` is true. Meaning `componentDidMount` will not fire in `MySecuredComponent` until `loggedIn` is true.

Comment: But my componentDidMount code still ran and caused the bug